# Nivo Slider box effects not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I'm working on a Nivo Slider for my website and I try to use the box effects, such as 'boxRain' and 'boxRainGrow'. But they just don't work. The images change without a transition. But when I replace the box effects by the default effects such as 'slideUp' and 'fade' they are working.

Is it the jquery version I'm using (latest)? Or is it just a problem of the Nivo Slider?

Thanks

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                        <img src="images/slideshow/1.jpg" alt="image 1" />
                        <img src="images/slideshow/2.jpg" alt="image 2" />
                        <img src="images/slideshow/3.jpg" alt="image 3" />
                        <img src="images/slideshow/4.jpg" alt="image 4" />
                        <img src="images/slideshow/5.jpg" alt="image 5" />
                        <img src="images/slideshow/6.jpg" alt="image 6" />
                        <img src="images/slideshow/7.jpg" alt="image 7" />
                    </div>
```

default.css:

```
/*
Skin Name: Nivo Slider Default Theme
Skin URI: http://nivo.dev7studios.com
Description: The default skin for the Nivo Slider.
Version: 1.3
Author: Gilbert Pellegrom
Author URI: http://dev7studios.com
Supports Thumbs: true
*/

.theme-default .nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    background:#fff url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;*/
    text-align: center;
}
.theme-default .nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
.theme-default .nivoSlider a {
    border:0;
    display:block;
}

.theme-default .nivo-controlNav {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background:url(images/bullets.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
    margin: 0;
}
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav a.active {
    background-position:0 -22px;
}

.theme-default .nivo-directionNav a {
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:url(images/arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.theme-default:hover .nivo-directionNav a { opacity: 1; }
.theme-default a.nivo-nextNav {
    background-position:-30px 0;
    right:15px;
}
.theme-default a.nivo-prevNav {
    left:15px;
}

.theme-default .nivo-caption {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.theme-default .nivo-caption a {
    color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
}
.theme-default .nivo-caption a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}

.theme-default .nivo-controlNav.nivo-thumbs-enabled {
    width: 100%;
}
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav.nivo-thumbs-enabled a {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav.nivo-thumbs-enabled img {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    height: auto;
}
```

nivo-slider.css:

```
/*
 * jQuery Nivo Slider v3.2
 * http://nivo.dev7studios.com
 *
 * Copyright 2012, Dev7studios
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

/* The Nivo Slider styles */
.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    max-width: none;
}
.nivo-main-image {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative !important; 
    width: 100% !important;
}

/* If an image is wrapped in a link */
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index:6;
    display:none;
    background:white; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); 
    opacity:0;
}
/* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
}
.nivo-box {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.nivo-box img { display:block; }

/* Caption styles */
.nivo-caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    z-index:8;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=8);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.nivo-caption p {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
}
.nivo-caption a {
    display:inline !important;
}
.nivo-html-caption {
    display:none;
}
/* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    z-index:9;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-prevNav {
    left:0px;
}
.nivo-nextNav {
    right:0px;
}
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.nivo-controlNav a {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1000;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

And jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js :

```
/*
 * jQuery Nivo Slider v3.2
 * http://nivo.dev7studios.com
 *
 * Copyright 2012, Dev7studios
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

(function(e){var t=function(t,n){var r=e.extend({},e.fn.nivoSlider.defaults,n);var i={currentSlide:0,currentImage:"",totalSlides:0,running:false,paused:false,stop:false,controlNavEl:false};var s=e(t);s.data("nivo:vars",i).addClass("nivoSlider");var o=s.children();o.each(function(){var t=e(this);var n="";if(!t.is("img")){if(t.is("a")){t.addClass("nivo-imageLink");n=t}t=t.find("img:first")}var r=r===0?t.attr("width"):t.width(),s=s===0?t.attr("height"):t.height();if(n!==""){n.css("display","none")}t.css("display","none");i.totalSlides++});if(r.randomStart){r.startSlide=Math.floor(Math.random()*i.totalSlides)}if(r.startSlide>0){if(r.startSlide>=i.totalSlides){r.startSlide=i.totalSlides-1}i.currentSlide=r.startSlide}if(e(o[i.currentSlide]).is("img")){i.currentImage=e(o[i.currentSlide])}else{i.currentImage=e(o[i.currentSlide]).find("img:first")}if(e(o[i.currentSlide]).is("a")){e(o[i.currentSlide]).css("display","block")}var u=e("<img/>").addClass("nivo-main-image");u.attr("src",i.currentImage.attr("src")).show();s.append(u);e(window).resize(function(){s.children("img").width(s.width());u.attr("src",i.currentImage.attr("src"));u.stop().height("auto");e(".nivo-slice").remove();e(".nivo-box").remove()});s.append(e('<div class="nivo-caption"></div>'));var a=function(t){var n=e(".nivo-caption",s);if(i.currentImage.attr("title")!=""&&i.currentImage.attr("title")!=undefined){var r=i.currentImage.attr("title");if(r.substr(0,1)=="#")r=e(r).html();if(n.css("display")=="block"){setTimeout(function(){n.html(r)},t.animSpeed)}else{n.html(r);n.stop().fadeIn(t.animSpeed)}}else{n.stop().fadeOut(t.animSpeed)}};a(r);var f=0;if(!r.manualAdvance&&o.length>1){f=setInterval(function(){d(s,o,r,false)},r.pauseTime)}if(r.directionNav){s.append('<div class="nivo-directionNav"><a class="nivo-prevNav">'+r.prevText+'</a><a class="nivo-nextNav">'+r.nextText+"</a></div>");e(s).on("click","a.nivo-prevNav",function(){if(i.running){return false}clearInterval(f);f="";i.currentSlide-=2;d(s,o,r,"prev")});e(s).on("click","a.nivo-nextNav",function(){if(i.running){return false}clearInterval(f);f="";d(s,o,r,"next")})}if(r.controlNav){i.controlNavEl=e('<div class="nivo-controlNav"></div>');s.after(i.controlNavEl);for(var l=0;l<o.length;l++){if(r.controlNavThumbs){i.controlNavEl.addClass("nivo-thumbs-enabled");var c=o.eq(l);if(!c.is("img")){c=c.find("img:first")}if(c.attr("data-thumb"))i.controlNavEl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+l+'"><img src="'+c.attr("data-thumb")+'" alt="" /></a>')}else{i.controlNavEl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+l+'">'+(l+1)+"</a>")}}e("a:eq("+i.currentSlide+")",i.controlNavEl).addClass("active");e("a",i.controlNavEl).bind("click",function(){if(i.running)return false;if(e(this).hasClass("active"))return false;clearInterval(f);f="";u.attr("src",i.currentImage.attr("src"));i.currentSlide=e(this).attr("rel")-1;d(s,o,r,"control")})}if(r.pauseOnHover){s.hover(function(){i.paused=true;clearInterval(f);f=""},function(){i.paused=false;if(f===""&&!r.manualAdvance){f=setInterval(function(){d(s,o,r,false)},r.pauseTime)}})}s.bind("nivo:animFinished",function(){u.attr("src",i.currentImage.attr("src"));i.running=false;e(o).each(function(){if(e(this).is("a")){e(this).css("display","none")}});if(e(o[i.currentSlide]).is("a")){e(o[i.currentSlide]).css("display","block")}if(f===""&&!i.paused&&!r.manualAdvance){f=setInterval(function(){d(s,o,r,false)},r.pauseTime)}r.afterChange.call(this)});var h=function(t,n,r){if(e(r.currentImage).parent().is("a"))e(r.currentImage).parent().css("display","block");e('img[src="'+r.currentImage.attr("src")+'"]',t).not(".nivo-main-image,.nivo-control img").width(t.width()).css("visibility","hidden").show();var i=e('img[src="'+r.currentImage.attr("src")+'"]',t).not(".nivo-main-image,.nivo-control img").parent().is("a")?e('img[src="'+r.currentImage.attr("src")+'"]',t).not(".nivo-main-image,.nivo-control img").parent().height():e('img[src="'+r.currentImage.attr("src")+'"]',t).not(".nivo-main-image,.nivo-control img").height();for(var s=0;s<n.slices;s++){var o=Math.round(t.width()/n.slices);if(s===n.slices-1){t.append(e('<div class="nivo-slice" name="'+s+'"><img src="'+r.currentImage.attr("src")+'" style="position:absolute; width:'+t.width()+"px; height:auto; display:block !important; top:0; left:-"+(o+s*o-o)+'px;" /></div>').css({left:o*s+"px",width:t.width()-o*s+"px",height:i+"px",opacity:"0",overflow:"hidden"}))}else{t.append(e('<div class="nivo-slice" name="'+s+'"><img src="'+r.currentImage.attr("src")+'" style="position:absolute; width:'+t.width()+"px; height:auto; display:block !important; top:0; left:-"+(o+s*o-o)+'px;" /></div>').css({left:o*s+"px",width:o+"px",height:i+"px",opacity:"0",overflow:"hidden"}))}}e(".nivo-slice",t).height(i);u.stop().animate({height:e(r.currentImage).height()},n.animSpeed)};var p=function(t,n,r){if(e(r.currentImage).parent().is("a"))e(r.currentImage).parent().css("display","block");e('img[src="'+r.currentImage.attr("src")+'"]',t).not(".nivo-main-image,.nivo-control img").width(t.width()).css("visibility","hidden").show();var i=Math.round(t.width()/n.boxCols),s=Math.round(e('img[src="'+r.currentImage.attr("src")+'"]',t).not(".nivo-main-image,.nivo-control img").height()/n.boxRows);for(var o=0;o<n.boxRows;o++){for(var a=0;a<n.boxCols;a++){if(a===n.boxCols-1){t.append(e('<div class="nivo-box" name="'+a+'" rel="'+o+'"><img src="'+r.currentImage.attr("src")+'" style="position:absolute; width:'+t.width()+"px; height:auto; display:block; top:-"+s*o+"px; left:-"+i*a+'px;" /></div>').css({opacity:0,left:i*a+"px",top:s*o+"px",width:t.width()-i*a+"px"}));e('.nivo-box[name="'+a+'"]',t).height(e('.nivo-box[name="'+a+'"] img',t).height()+"px")}else{t.append(e('<div class="nivo-box" name="'+a+'" rel="'+o+'"><img src="'+r.currentImage.attr("src")+'" style="position:absolute; width:'+t.width()+"px; height:auto; display:block; top:-"+s*o+"px; left:-"+i*a+'px;" /></div>').css({opacity:0,left:i*a+"px",top:s*o+"px",width:i+"px"}));e('.nivo-box[name="'+a+'"]',t).height(e('.nivo-box[name="'+a+'"] img',t).height()+"px")}}}u.stop().animate({height:e(r.currentImage).height()},n.animSpeed)};var d=function(t,n,r,i){var s=t.data("nivo:vars");if(s&&s.currentSlide===s.totalSlides-1){r.lastSlide.call(this)}if((!s||s.stop)&&!i){return false}r.beforeChange.call(this);if(!i){u.attr("src",s.currentImage.attr("src"))}else{if(i==="prev"){u.attr("src",s.currentImage.attr("src"))}if(i==="next"){u.attr("src",s.currentImage.attr("src"))}}s.currentSlide++;if(s.currentSlide===s.totalSlides){s.currentSlide=0;r.slideshowEnd.call(this)}if(s.currentSlide<0){s.currentSlide=s.totalSlides-1}if(e(n[s.currentSlide]).is("img")){s.currentImage=e(n[s.currentSlide])}else{s.currentImage=e(n[s.currentSlide]).find("img:first")}if(r.controlNav){e("a",s.controlNavEl).removeClass("active");e("a:eq("+s.currentSlide+")",s.controlNavEl).addClass("active")}a(r);e(".nivo-slice",t).remove();e(".nivo-box",t).remove();var o=r.effect,f="";if(r.effect==="random"){f=new Array("sliceDownRight","sliceDownLeft","sliceUpRight","sliceUpLeft","sliceUpDown","sliceUpDownLeft","fold","fade","boxRandom","boxRain","boxRainReverse","boxRainGrow","boxRainGrowReverse");o=f[Math.floor(Math.random()*(f.length+1))];if(o===undefined){o="fade"}}if(r.effect.indexOf(",")!==-1){f=r.effect.split(",");o=f[Math.floor(Math.random()*f.length)];if(o===undefined){o="fade"}}if(s.currentImage.attr("data-transition")){o=s.currentImage.attr("data-transition")}s.running=true;var l=0,c=0,d="",m="",g="",y="";if(o==="sliceDown"||o==="sliceDownRight"||o==="sliceDownLeft"){h(t,r,s);l=0;c=0;d=e(".nivo-slice",t);if(o==="sliceDownLeft"){d=e(".nivo-slice",t)._reverse()}d.each(function(){var n=e(this);n.css({top:"0px"});if(c===r.slices-1){setTimeout(function(){n.animate({opacity:"1.0"},r.animSpeed,"",function(){t.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})},100+l)}else{setTimeout(function(){n.animate({opacity:"1.0"},r.animSpeed)},100+l)}l+=50;c++})}else if(o==="sliceUp"||o==="sliceUpRight"||o==="sliceUpLeft"){h(t,r,s);l=0;c=0;d=e(".nivo-slice",t);if(o==="sliceUpLeft"){d=e(".nivo-slice",t)._reverse()}d.each(function(){var n=e(this);n.css({bottom:"0px"});if(c===r.slices-1){setTimeout(function(){n.animate({opacity:"1.0"},r.animSpeed,"",function(){t.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})},100+l)}else{setTimeout(function(){n.animate({opacity:"1.0"},r.animSpeed)},100+l)}l+=50;c++})}else if(o==="sliceUpDown"||o==="sliceUpDownRight"||o==="sliceUpDownLeft"){h(t,r,s);l=0;c=0;var b=0;d=e(".nivo-slice",t);if(o==="sliceUpDownLeft"){d=e(".nivo-slice",t)._reverse()}d.each(function(){var n=e(this);if(c===0){n.css("top","0px");c++}else{n.css("bottom","0px");c=0}if(b===r.slices-1){setTimeout(function(){n.animate({opacity:"1.0"},r.animSpeed,"",function(){t.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})},100+l)}else{setTimeout(function(){n.animate({opacity:"1.0"},r.animSpeed)},100+l)}l+=50;b++})}else if(o==="fold"){h(t,r,s);l=0;c=0;e(".nivo-slice",t).each(function(){var n=e(this);var i=n.width();n.css({top:"0px",width:"0px"});if(c===r.slices-1){setTimeout(function(){n.animate({width:i,opacity:"1.0"},r.animSpeed,"",function(){t.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})},100+l)}else{setTimeout(function(){n.animate({width:i,opacity:"1.0"},r.animSpeed)},100+l)}l+=50;c++})}else if(o==="fade"){h(t,r,s);m=e(".nivo-slice:first",t);m.css({width:t.width()+"px"});m.animate({opacity:"1.0"},r.animSpeed*2,"",function(){t.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})}else if(o==="slideInRight"){h(t,r,s);m=e(".nivo-slice:first",t);m.css({width:"0px",opacity:"1"});m.animate({width:t.width()+"px"},r.animSpeed*2,"",function(){t.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})}else if(o==="slideInLeft"){h(t,r,s);m=e(".nivo-slice:first",t);m.css({width:"0px",opacity:"1",left:"",right:"0px"});m.animate({width:t.width()+"px"},r.animSpeed*2,"",function(){m.css({left:"0px",right:""});t.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})}else if(o==="boxRandom"){p(t,r,s);g=r.boxCols*r.boxRows;c=0;l=0;y=v(e(".nivo-box",t));y.each(function(){var n=e(this);if(c===g-1){setTimeout(function(){n.animate({opacity:"1"},r.animSpeed,"",function(){t.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})},100+l)}else{setTimeout(function(){n.animate({opacity:"1"},r.animSpeed)},100+l)}l+=20;c++})}else if(o==="boxRain"||o==="boxRainReverse"||o==="boxRainGrow"||o==="boxRainGrowReverse"){p(t,r,s);g=r.boxCols*r.boxRows;c=0;l=0;var w=0;var E=0;var S=[];S[w]=[];y=e(".nivo-box",t);if(o==="boxRainReverse"||o==="boxRainGrowReverse"){y=e(".nivo-box",t)._reverse()}y.each(function(){S[w][E]=e(this);E++;if(E===r.boxCols){w++;E=0;S[w]=[]}});for(var x=0;x<r.boxCols*2;x++){var T=x;for(var N=0;N<r.boxRows;N++){if(T>=0&&T<r.boxCols){(function(n,i,s,u,a){var f=e(S[n][i]);var l=f.width();var c=f.height();if(o==="boxRainGrow"||o==="boxRainGrowReverse"){f.width(0).height(0)}if(u===a-1){setTimeout(function(){f.animate({opacity:"1",width:l,height:c},r.animSpeed/1.3,"",function(){t.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})},100+s)}else{setTimeout(function(){f.animate({opacity:"1",width:l,height:c},r.animSpeed/1.3)},100+s)}})(N,T,l,c,g);c++}T--}l+=100}}};var v=function(e){for(var t,n,r=e.length;r;t=parseInt(Math.random()*r,10),n=e[--r],e[r]=e[t],e[t]=n);return e};var m=function(e){if(this.console&&typeof console.log!=="undefined"){console.log(e)}};this.stop=function(){if(!e(t).data("nivo:vars").stop){e(t).data("nivo:vars").stop=true;m("Stop Slider")}};this.start=function(){if(e(t).data("nivo:vars").stop){e(t).data("nivo:vars").stop=false;m("Start Slider")}};r.afterLoad.call(this);return this};e.fn.nivoSlider=function(n){return this.each(function(r,i){var s=e(this);if(s.data("nivoslider")){return s.data("nivoslider")}var o=new t(this,n);s.data("nivoslider",o)})};e.fn.nivoSlider.defaults={effect:"boxRandom",slices:20,boxCols:8,boxRows:4,animSpeed:1000,pauseTime:4000,startSlide:0,directionNav:true,controlNav:true,controlNavThumbs:false,pauseOnHover:true,manualAdvance:false,prevText:"Prev",nextText:"Next",randomStart:false,beforeChange:function(){},afterChange:function(){},slideshowEnd:function(){},lastSlide:function(){},afterLoad:function(){}};e.fn._reverse=[].reverse})(jQuery)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code or a fiddle. Most likely not an issue with Nivo Slider. I have seen this effect working in some demos.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I have posted the code, hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can see the effects myself using the code you provided. Are you sure you know how these effects look like? Nivo Slider 3.2 requires jQuery v1.7+ and 1.7.2 worked for me.

Comment: @MrUpsidown when I add 'data-transition="boxRain"' within the img tag, the images just flashes without any effect. But when I replace the boxRain by 'fade' it works fine. I'm using jquery version 1.10.2

Comment: Have you tried setting the effect globally like $('#slider').nivoSlider({ effect : 'boxRain' }); - what happens?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I figured it out! First I linked to my images in a folder. Then I uploaded them to my website and replaced the source of the images by http://mywebsite.com/images/slideshow/1.jpg and then it worked. I find it really strange, but whatever. However, thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you found the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Some nivo-silder effect seem to do not work. customize this effect list.(line 350)

```
anims = new Array('sliceDownRight','sliceDownLeft','sliceUpRight','sliceUpLeft','sliceUpDown','sliceUpDownLeft','fold','fade');
```